# The n-th derivative of $\frac{1}{(x-1)(x+1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Let's say that we know that the (n-th derivative of) $\frac{1}{n}^{(n)} = (-1)^nn!x^{-(n+1)}$

Can we then use the formula and the product form of a derivative for $(\frac{1}{(x-1)(x+1)})^{(n)} = \frac{1}{x-1}^{(n)}*\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x-1}*(\frac{1}{x+1})^{(n)}$

And then we use the formula.

Or is this not correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not correct.

On the other hand,$$\frac1{(x-1)(x+1)}=\frac{1/2}{x-1}-\frac{1/2}{x+1},$$and you can use this.